# Setting state for items generated via iterator/map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I am having some issues setting state/updating the input text value in the handleChange function.

I have a component which on loading of a page loops through a holes iterator and generates some divs:

```
{holes.map((item, index) => (
          <React.Fragment>
          
             <div className="griditem">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="input"
                label="playerAScore"
                data-hole-number={item.holeNumber}
                data-id={item.id}
                value="10"
                id={players[0]?.id && `${players[0].id}-${item.holeNumber}`}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  handleChange(
                    event,
                    index,
                    item.par,
                    item.stroke,
                    handicapPlayerA,
                    item.holeNumber,
                    item.id,
                    players[0].id
                  )
                }
                ref={inputRef}
              />
            </div>
              <div className="griditem">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="input"
                label="playerBScore"
                value="20"
                id={players[1]?.id && `${players[1].id}-${item.holeNumber}`}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  handleChange(
                    event,
                    index,
                    item.par,
                    item.stroke,
                    handicapPlayerB,
                    item.holeNumber,
                    item.id,
                    players[1].id
                  )
                }
              />
            </div>
            <div className="griditem">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="input"
                label="playerCScore"
                id={players[2]?.id && `${players[2].id}-${item.holeNumber}`}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  handleChange(
                    event,
                    index,
                    item.par,
                    item.stroke,
                    handicapPlayerC,
                    item.holeNumber,
                    item.id,
                    players[2].id
                  )
                }
              />
            </div>          
        </React.Fragment>
  ))}
```

My handleChange function looks like this:

```
const handleChange = (
event,
inputId,
index,
par,
stroke,
handicap,
holeNumber,
holeId,
playerId
  ) => {
    const inputValue = event.target.value;
    const inputElementId = event.target.id;

     // Update the inputValues state with the new value
    setInputValues((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [inputElementId]: inputValue,
    }));

    const score = calculatePoints(par, inputValue, handicap, stroke);

    // Update the input value directly
    const inputElement = document.getElementById(inputElementId);
    inputElement.value = score;

    alert(inputElement.value);

    // Trigger a re-render of the component
    setRenderKey((prevKey) => prevKey + 1);

    // Update the corresponding state
    return score;
};
```

I have some const set for inputValues and renderKey and other to useState:

```
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({});
  const [renderKey, setRenderKey] = useState(0);
```

I've tried numerous different ways to get it to update the value of the input fields but it doesnt.  I can see that in the handlechange everything is set correctly but react doesnt update the value after exiting the handleChange function.

Comment: why did you hardcode the value to 10?

Comment: I just wanted to make it wasnt an issue with how it was rendering the values using another function I had.  Either way setting it initially surely doesnt mean it can't be overwritten?

Comment: Why are you passing individual `item` properties. Just pass the index of the item and access it in state.

Comment: Yes I could do but I just want to provide an input to the function so that I could easily console.log each one. Again that isn't the reason why its not setting the value of the input text fields.  Or are you suggesting by just setting item as the state?  If so can you provide an example: 
  const [item, setItems] = useState([]);
....
    onChange={(event) =>
                      handleChange(
                        event,
                        index
                      )

handleChange(event, index) {
 const newItem = [...item];
    newItem[index] = event.target.value;
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to explicitly set the state of the players and holes in the useEffect() after calling the rest endpoints:

```
  const [holes, Setholes] = useState("");
  const [playerA, setPlayerA] = useState("");
  const [playerB, setPlayerB] = useState("");
  
  setPlayerA(response.data.players[0].name);
  setPlayerB(response.data.players[1].name);
  setHoles(response.data.holes);
```